# Having issues with redirecting to pages

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am using Android Studio and in my App there are 2 pages. One is a Search Page where the user has to key in information in order to search. One of the EditTexts requires Date and Time, and instead of typing it in, clicking on the EditText will redirect the user to the second Page where he will select a date and time from the CalendarView and Time Picker. When he clicks on 'Done' button, the date and time will then be populated into the previous mentioned EditText.

The issue? App crashes when that happened, please help me with the codes.

Here's the code for the first page:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etPickUp, etDropOff, etRentS, etRentE;
Button btnBack, btnSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    etPickUp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPickUp);
    etDropOff = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDropOff);

    etRentS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRentS);
    etRentS.setFocusable(false);
    etRentS.setClickable(true);
    etRentS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent rentS = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, RentStartActivity.class);
            startActivity(rentS);
        }
    });

    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent back = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, LandingActivity.class);
            startActivity(back);
        }
    });

    String date1="";
    String time1="";
    Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle1 != null)
    {
        date1 = bundle1.getString("Date1");
        time1 = bundle1.getString("Time1");
    }
    etRentS.setText(date1);
    etRentS.setText(time1);


    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And here's the code for the second page:

```
public class RentStartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnDone1, btnCancel1;
CalendarView calendar1;
TimePicker time1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rent_start);

    calendar1 = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar1);
    time1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time1);

    btnDone1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone1);
    btnDone1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent done1 = new Intent();
            done1.putExtra("Date1", calendar1.getDate());
            done1.putExtra("Time1", time1.getDrawingTime());
            startActivity(done1);
        }
    });

    btnCancel1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel1);
    btnCancel1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent cancel1 = new Intent(RentStartActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(cancel1);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: When the app crashes, there should be a stack trace printed to the device console log - can you find that and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to which activity should be started while defining intent object.

```
            Intent done1 = new Intent();
            done1.putExtra("Date1", calendar1.getDate());
            done1.putExtra("Time1", time1.getDrawingTime());
            startActivity(done1);
```

You should add something like this

```
Intent done1=new Intent(SearchActivity.this, RentStartActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an activity result. You need to first open the second activity using this code:

```
startActivityForResult( RentStartActivity, RentStartActivityResultCode )
```

Where `RentStartActivityResultCode` is a constant int used to identify the result.

In the second activity, use this code in the done button's action handler to send back the result:

```
Intent output = new Intent();
output.putExtra("Date1", calendar1.getDate().getTime() );
output.putExtra("Hour", time1.getHour() );
output.putExtra("Minute", time1.getMinute() );
setResult( RESULT_OK, output );
finish();
```

And finally, in the first activity use this code to read the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == RentStartActivityResultCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ) {
        Date date1 = new Date( data.getLongExtra("Date1") );
        int hour = data.getIntExtra("Hour");
        int minute = data.getIntExtra("Minute");
    }
}
```